# How to fix the constant variance assumption?

Tags: regression, variance, data-transformation, residuals, minitab

We have a project where we have to find the best model using a large set of data. In our current model there are 10 variables, some quantitative, and a few that are qualitative. When we first do regression in Minitab we see that the constant variance assumption is violated because the residual graph is fanning out. Furthermore, the probability plot has an S shape which is not the straight line that we want. We therefore decided to do a natural log transformation on our dependent variable and this straightened our probability plot significantly, but now our residual graph looks like a big clump of points concentrated in one area.

Any suggestions on how to fix it? We have tried transforming some independent variables as well, and it didn't fix it.

Is there something that we should be looking for? What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you clarify with some plots that show what "clump" means and give a sense of the domain?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than transform your data to meet the assumptions of your model, you should change your model to fit your data.

There are several methods of regression that do not assume constant variance. The closest to "regular" regression is probably robust regression. There are several methods of doing this and it can be hard to choose the right one. Compared to the usual regression, they are not quite as powerful (when the assumptions are met) and are computationally intensive (although this becomes less of a problem over time, as computers get faster).

Another method is quantile regression, which regresses on the quantiles (such as the median, rather than the mean. I am a fan of this method.

Farther afield are things like regression trees and related methods. These can be unstable with small data sets, but do have some nice properties and assume very little about the data.